# How to webscrape sub object “address” using json

Tags: json, excel, vba

Address field is coming blank in excel sheet

results(r, 4) = review("streetAddress")

during webscraping; I am importing fields from websites and data accordingly, please guide me.

Sheet A1 = https://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/restaurants?page=

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub GetRestuarantInfo()

    Dim s As String, re As Object, p As String, page As Long, r As String, json As Object 'Variable Definations
    Const START_PAGE As Long = 2
    Const END_PAGE As Long = 4
    Const RESULTS_PER_PAGE As Long = 40

    p = "\[{""@context"".*?\]"
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False            
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")    
    For page = START_PAGE To END_PAGE ' Run for loop for defined Page numbers
            .Open "GET", Sheet1.Range("A1") & page, False 
            .send 
             If .Status = 200 Then 
             s = .responseText 
                r = GetValue(re, s, p) 
                If r <> "Not Found" Then 
                    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(r)
                    WriteOutResults page, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, json
                End If

            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Sub WriteOutResults(ByVal page As Long, ByVal RESULTS_PER_PAGE As Long, ByVal json As Object)
    Dim sheetName As String, results(), r As Long, headers(), ws As Worksheet
    ReDim results(1 To RESULTS_PER_PAGE, 1 To 4)

    sheetName = "page" & page ' This module is just to write results pagewise which is not needed in your case
    headers = Array("Name", "Website", "Tel", "Address") 'Defination of headers
    If Not WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then ' Creation of sheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = sheetName
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ClearContents
    End If
    With ws
        Dim review As Object
        For Each review In json ' Bringing results from Json to excel sheet
            r = r + 1
            results(r, 1) = review("name") 'write results of name field
            results(r, 2) = review("url") 'write results of url field
            results(r, 3) = review("telephone") 'write results of telephone field
             results(r, 4) = review("streetAddress") 'write results of telephone field
        Next
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers 
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True 
        .MultiLine = True  

        .IgnoreCase = False 'Use case-insensitive matching.
        .pattern = pattern 'The pattern (written in Regex) which you want to match against (e.g. “(.*)”)

        'Test (string) – returns True if the pattern can be matched agaist the provided string
         'Web Link: https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/
        If .Test(inputString) Then
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0)
        Else
            GetValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)") 
End Function
```

I keep getting empty of range of address for the following code, I'm new to VBA so would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json access path is different for address

`review("address")` gives a dictionary

[image]

You would need to access individual lines by key or, as I do, join all the items of the dictionary to create a single space separated string for the full address.

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetRestuarantInfo()
    Dim s As String, re As Object, p As String, page As Long, r As String, json As Object 'Variable Definations
    Const START_PAGE As Long = 2
    Const END_PAGE As Long = 4
    Const RESULTS_PER_PAGE As Long = 40

    p = "\[{""@context"".*?\]"
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For page = START_PAGE To END_PAGE        ' Run for loop for defined Page numbers
            .Open "GET", "https://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/restaurants?page=" & page, False
            .send
            If .Status = 200 Then
                s = .responseText
                r = GetValue(re, s, p)
                If r <> "Not Found" Then
                    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(r)
                    WriteOutResults page, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, json
                End If

            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub WriteOutResults(ByVal page As Long, ByVal RESULTS_PER_PAGE As Long, ByVal json As Object)
    Dim sheetName As String, results(), r As Long, headers(), ws As Worksheet
    ReDim results(1 To RESULTS_PER_PAGE, 1 To 4)

    sheetName = "page" & page                    ' This module is just to write results pagewise which is not needed in your case
    headers = Array("Name", "Website", "Tel", "Address") 'Defination of headers
    If Not WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then       ' Creation of sheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = sheetName
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
    End If
    With ws
        Dim review As Object
        For Each review In json                  ' Bringing results from Json to excel sheet
            r = r + 1
            results(r, 1) = review("name")       'write results of name field
            results(r, 2) = review("url")        'write results of url field
            results(r, 3) = review("telephone")  'write results of telephone field
            results(r, 4) = Replace$(Join$(review("address").items, " "), "PostalAddress ", vbNullString) 'write results of telephone field
        Next
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True

        .IgnoreCase = False                      'Use case-insensitive matching.
        .pattern = pattern                       'The pattern (written in Regex) which you want to match against (e.g. “(.*)”)

        'Test (string) – returns True if the pattern can be matched agaist the provided string
        'Web Link: https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/
        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0)
        Else
            GetValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Comment: beat me to it by a minute or so :-(

Comment: How to open that image from the website?

Comment: You don’t. I posted the .responseText into a tool

Comment: Which tool as I always do this by going to web & then inspecting element.

Comment: Google Jsonviewer and any of the top results should help. Otherwise I can post name when at a computer.